# fatal error on a drupal site

Tags: files

I have a site based on drupal. Few weeks back an error appeared on our site

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_entity_file_presave() (previously
>   declared in
>   /home/newprofi/public_html/new/sites/default/modules/file_entity/file_entity.module:177)
>   in
>   /home/newprofi/public_html/new/sites/default/modules/file_entity/file_entity.file.inc
>   on line 37

it happened after an upgrade that distorted our theme, and only restoring could have saved that.

i tried to find duplicates of that module, but there is nothing on our servers.
Is there anything else i could do to fix that?

Thanks,
Noam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had seen similar error in the past and I followed these steps which worked for me:

1. Manually disable the module in db
2. Clear the cache
3. Re-enable the module